# Motor for a sukkah rooflight

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanical

im designing a motor for a roof light but will need to be disengaged from the motor and be able to open and close without any electricity.
any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: what's a roof light? ... what is your specific question?

Comment: without electricity? So water pressure should be an option, or big masses turning a shaft like those clocks...

Comment: I think the OP wants a motor drive mechanism to open a skylight / roof window by motor but with a way to disengage the drive for manual opening / closing.

Comment: Two simple ways without disengaging: (1) superimposed where how open it is = a manual setting + a motor setting; (2) backdrive where motor in the off state can be turned manually